# Use Parse.com with another realtime service

Tags: parse-platform, firebase, real-time

I would like to build a realtime app with parse.com, am I better of using parse.com's push notification feature to implement the realtime part or shall I use firebase.com or even something else?

Comment: Can you give us a running example of what you're looking for ?  Also something you might have tried would help answer your question! Its quite broad right now!

Comment: Looking to make a realtime text chat web app. I haven't started yet...

Comment: I would start with something simple then, without going through parse//firebase etc first.. Maybe try create one in websockets and nodeJS to get your head around what needs to be achieved. Then will be much easier for you to decide what build framework you would like to use. Create a skeleton application first, and then move to step 2 :)

Comment: Consider using [http://framework.realtime.co/messaging](http://framework.realtime.co/messaging) for the real-time communication between devices (including mobile push notifications) or even [Realtime Cloud Storage](http://framework.realtime.co/storage) for data backend and data-sync between devices.